# Is there is any relationship between determinant and spectral radius of the matrix?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius, spectra

We all know that determinant is the product of the eigen values of a matrix. I have found some general term for the determinant of the adjacency matrices from some series of graphs. Can i establish some relation between the determinant and spectral radius of those graphs?

Comment: The determinant is $\prod$ of eigenvalues, the spectral radius is the $\max$. No connection.

Comment: @markvs *max absolute value

Answer (score 1):

Gutman defined the energy of a graph $G$ as the sum of the absolute values of its eigenvalues
$$
E(G) = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|.
$$
If we order the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix in non-decreasing order $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$, the square of the energy satisfies
$$
   E(G)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2
          + \sum_{i \neq j} |\lambda_i||\lambda_j|.
$$
It's well-known that $\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2$ is twice the number of graph edges, hereafter denoted $2m$. We can use the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality to change the second summation to a product of $n(n-1)$ terms,
$$
   E(G)^2 \geq 2m + n(n-1)\left(\prod_{i \neq j} |\lambda_i| |\lambda_j|\right)^{1/(n(n-1))}.
$$
This product is bounded below by $|\det(A)|^{2/n}$ and the energy satisfies
$$
   E(G) \geq \sqrt{2m + n(n-1) |\det(A)|^{2/n}}.
$$

The largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix is always positive, so we can rewrite the above as
$$
   \lambda_n \geq \sqrt{2m + n(n-1) |\det(A)|^{2/n}}
             - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |\lambda_i|.
$$
This is the strongest relationship that I know of between the determinant and spectral radius of an adjacency matrix.

Comment: thank you very much sir for the inequality...